# how do i run a .vbs file from a link in html

Tags: html

My folder looks like this Initial (folder\css,img,js,vbs,Main.html,Sub.html,sup.html)

I am supposed to link the .vbs script here and have it run from the file but it opens up a new window and shows the code from that file. I have tried script tags inside the link but it didn't work out very well.

My code looks like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href="vbs/code.vbs">Link</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use HTML like this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <script language="VBScript" type="text/vbscript" src="yourfile.vbs"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
 </body>
</html>
```

[Check this](http://www.herongyang.com/VBScript/IE-Browser-Include-VBScript-Codes-as-External-Files.html)